# Tail pointing at the last node?

Tags: c++

```
void IntList::push_front(int value){
    IntNode *holder = new IntNode(value);
    holder -> next = head;
    head = holder;
    if(head == 0){
        tail = head;
    }
    tail = holder;
}
```

Header

```
#ifndef INTLIST_H
#define INTLIST_H

struct IntNode{
    int data;
    IntNode *next;
    IntNode(int data) : data(data), next(0) {}
};

class IntList{
private:
    IntNode *head;
    IntNode *tail;
public:
    void push_front(int value);
};

#endif
```

How do I get tail to point at the last tail node?  I have the if statement so that it is set to 0 if the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
head = holder;
if(head == 0){
    tail = head;
}
```

The steps above are in the wrong order: you're setting head to holder (which will never be 0 because if the memory allocation failed you'd get an exception, and if it worked you'll get a pointer to the allocated node), then testing if head still equals 0.

You could just reverse their order, but IMHO it's cleaner to test tail directly anyway:

```
head = holder;
if (tail == nullptr)
    tail = head;
```

On pre-C++11 compilers you may not have `nullptr` - just use NULL or 0 or change to `if (!tail)`.